# Weblogic 12 Caused By: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /jms/MyCF in /app/webapp/myapp.war/.; remaining name '/jms/MyCF'

Tags: spring-boot, jms, weblogic

I have issue with JNDI resolving.

Regarding this page, if it is under Weblogic it should only have this property:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jms-jndi

```
spring.jms.jndi-name=java:/jms/MyCF
```

JmsTemplate is created automatically. Or it should. But it didn't.

I get this exception.

```
Caused By: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /jms/MyCF in /app/webapp/myapp.war/923245655.; remaining name '/jms/MyCF'
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1292)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.lookup(ApplicationNamingNode.java:144)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:307)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:435)
at weblogic.jndi.factories.java.ReadOnlyContextWrapper.lookup(ReadOnlyContextWrapper.java:45)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found what was an issue.

```
spring.jms.jndi-name=jms/MyCF
```

Simple as that. :)